# How to make a http 'GET' request with esp8266 and arduino?

Tags: http, arduino, server, esp8266

I have arduino mega2560 which is connected to a WiFi network using esp8266. and I have a server running on https://taub-ramym.c9.io (IP 126.128.47.440)
which has thees functions (that changes a flag value in my DB...):

taub-ramym.c9.io/empty

taub-ramym.c9.io/girls

taub-ramym.c9.io/boys

when I put thees http calls in a regular internet browser (chrome...), the flag changes succesfully. the same happens when I call for it from an android app.

but when I call for it from the arduino, it returns "OK", but nothing happens to the flag!
I uses this code (after connecting to the WiFi):

AT+CIPSTART="TCP","126.128.47.440",80 (returns OK)

AT+CIPSEND=121

GET taub-ramym.c9.io/girls HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: taub-ramym.c9.io\r\nUser-Agent: ESP8266_HTTP_Client\r\nConnection: keep-alive\r\n

returns OK but nothing happens in the DB...!
can you please help? I has spend more than a weak on it!!
thanks alot

Comment: Have you discovered how to make a POST request ? Can you help with some code, please? I have no idea how to make that, and I am struggling with this thing for a long time :( .

Comment: still have not succeded (GET request) ! tomorrow I am planning to use wireshark to chick if my TCP connection is OK .. 
for a POST requist use this 2 links:
http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=155218.0
https://github.com/McOffsky/Arduino_ESP8266_HTTP_Client

Comment: HTTP requests must be terminated with two consecutive cr/lf pairs, i.e., \r\n\r\n.  Also Connection: close is easier to deal with than keep-alive, it frees you from the need to include Content-length (which can take quite a bit of resources to compute, relatively speaking.)